# Problem using mutagen to set custom tags for MP4 file

Tags: python, python-3.x, mutagen

I am attempting to set custom ID3 tags on MP4 files using Python and Mutagen.  So far I have been able to create custom tags for MP3 files without any issues, but MP4 seems to be another issue altogether.

The initial error message I received was a TypeError stating that "can't concat str to bytes".  So instead of feeding the program a string I encoded it as a UTF-8 bytearray but it gave this error message:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

This error actually occurs within Mutagen itself.

Here is the code:

```
from mutagen.id3 import ID3
from mutagen.mp4 import MP4

def set_isbn(filename, isbn):
    if(filename.lower().endswith(".mp3")):
        tags = ID3(filename)
        tags.add(TXXX(encoding=3, desc=u'ISBN', text=str(isbn)))
        tags.save(filename)
    else:
        tags = MP4(filename)
        tags["----:TXXX:ISBN"] = bytearray(isbn, 'UTF-8')
        tags.save(filename)
```

The Mutagen docs are mostly very good but when it comes to custom MP4 tags all it states is the general setup of the mean:name:key.  Has anyone else ever been able to successfully implement custom tags for MP4 files?

Comment: What line are you receiving the exception on? It's not apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important things first: the only problem in your code is the conversion from `string` to `bytearray`. Taking a look at the source code of `mutagen`, in the part concerning specifically the `mp4` file type, there is a line that looks like this:

```
    ...
    if isinstance(x, bytes):
        x = [x]
        ...
```

where `x` is the value you supply. When the above condition is met, the value you gave is inserted inside a `list`, which has a "*dunder len*" method, hence can be the argument of the `len` function, that in turn will not raise `TypeError` when used as argument.

You should only edit your code by replacing the conversion to `bytearray` with the one to `bytes` as follows:

```
from mutagen.id3 import ID3
from mutagen.mp4 import MP4

def set_isbn(filename, isbn):
    if(filename.lower().endswith(".mp3")):
        tags = ID3(filename)
        tags.add(TXXX(encoding=3, desc=u'ISBN', text=str(isbn)))
        tags.save(filename)
    else:
        tags = MP4(filename)
        tags["----:TXXX:ISBN"] = bytes(isbn, 'UTF-8')
        tags.save(filename)
```

You will then avoid the above `TypeError` exception.